# How to do callback having some lines in my query

Tags: node.js

I have a function like this:

```
function get_users (v_user, callback){
   stmt = db.prepare("SELECT name FROM table_users where option = ?");
   stmt.bind(v_user);

   stmt.get(function(error,row){
      if(row){
         console.log(row.name) // only first line
      }
```

My problem is that, My query affect three lines (three names) and I need to access to all my results. Somebody know how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: If I remember correctly you access them by `row.name[0]` etc or perhaps `row[0].name` etc. But I may be wrong

Comment: I have tried and is not correct, for example if my first name is 'Aidin' 
row.name[0] = 'A' 
:(

Comment: row[0].name -> error in my console

Comment: Send back your rows to the client, use Google ARC or similar, send the get request to your server, look what the respons (row) looks like and then it should be easier.

Comment: oh, I think you just need to ommit `name` since that is all you get. Try: `row[0]` etc

Comment: row[0] - "undefined" (in my console).
row - "[object Object]
row.name - (Only first name)

Comment: what mysql lib do you use ?

Comment: Im using sqlite3: var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3'.verbose();

Comment: ok, are you sure you are getting more than one row? Try the ARC experiment I proposed.

Comment: Considering the answer given, you are not sure you get more than one row. You need to test it somehow to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback) you must use stmt.all() to get all results.

```
function get_users (v_user, callback){
  stmt = db.prepare("SELECT name FROM table_users where option = ?");
  stmt.bind(v_user);

  // instead of stmt.get()
  stmt.all(function(err,rows) {
    if (err)
      return callback(err);
    return callback(null, rows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! :)